# Xcode 7.0 The launch image set "LaunchImage" has 2 unassigned children

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, xcode7

I just updated xcode to 7.0 and fixed most of the bugs, but I keep getting this error message:The launch image set "LaunchImage" has 2 unassigned children. I already deleted the two unassigned children and still getting this error message.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to deep clean `Xcode` (command+alt+shift+K)

Comment: What does maj stand for?

Comment: Sorry I'm french, it's actually shift

Comment: Yeah it did. Thank you or Merci!

Comment: I'm having the same problem (not on LaunchImage" but on assets used by the app. Deep clean didn't help. Xcode 7.1 beta

Comment: And make sure no required images are missing :) I had that issue as well.

Answer (score 14):

If you click the problem , Xcode will lead you directly into the 
Images.xcassets , manually delete the two Unassigned images , rebuild it work fine for me.

Answer (score 9):

The deep clean didn't work for me. As trivial as it sounds, recreating the LaunchImages fixed the issue for me. I don't know why it happened in the first place, probably an Xcode 7 bug, but it works again.

Answer (score 5):

What you have to do is manually delete the two unassigned images, and then right click your image asset panes and choosing: App Icon & Launch Images > New iOS Launch Image. Once you click on that, a new set of launch image screen slots should populate. See the screenshot below for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case deep clean would not work until I manually deleted both unassigned images. For me the fix was a combination of all three answers above.

Answer (score 1):

Select the image. Open the attributes inspector and check that a device has been selected - i.e. all/universal. Then drag and drop the unassigned image into the appropriate image size.