# Xcode 7: warning: Ambiguous Content: The launch image set "LaunchImage" has 9 unassigned children

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, build

This is a warning I get from Xcode 7. Previously this worked. I tried doing the deep clean as per the [X-Code 7.0 The launch image set "LaunchImage" has 2 unassigned children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32695893/x-code-7-0-the-launch-image-set-launchimage-has-2-unassigned-children) post, but no luck. What can I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since someone else is also interested in this issue I'll post the solution that worked for me - As trivial as it sounds, recreating the LaunchImages fixed the issue. I don't know why it happened in the first place, probably an Xcode 7 bug, but it works again.

Comment: Actually in Xcode 7 they have placed empty screen for Launch Screen. By default nothing will appear. Try to Check by placing images and in settings general select launch screen